# tf.Print() output reduction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tf.Print()` to debug a model, but `tf.Print()` is printing too often. What are some good strategies to limit the output of this function, perhaps to be invoked on every nth epoch?

Comment: Does "printing too much" mean "printing too often"?

Comment: @rvinas Yes, looks like it prints for every batch, so multiple times per epoch. I've updated the question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can print output on every nth epoch as you mentioned in the question. Here is the basic example:

```
if epoch % n == 0:
    ...
```

Comment: This wouldn't work - the logics need to happen within the TF graph

Comment: It works for me too. So I guess under the hood, TF must convert the `if` and `%` to `Operation` nodes in the graphs, similar to what `tf.cond` achieves...

Comment: @rishai I guess you're using TF eager execution then. If that is not the case and you're running `tf.print` outside the graph, the solution `print(sess.run(tensor))` every `n` epochs would be trivial (you don't even need `tf.print`)

Answer (score 2):

You could hold a counter for the steps/epochs in a TF variable, and then use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) in combination with [tf.math.mod](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/floormod) to print the tensor when the counter is a multiple of `n`.

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def print_step(step):
    print_op = tf.print(step)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        out = tf.identity(step)
    return out


step = tf.Variable(0)
print_freq = 100

print_flag = tf.equal(tf.math.mod(step, print_freq), 0)
update_step = tf.assign(step, step + 1)
cond_print_op = tf.cond(print_flag,
                        lambda: print_step(update_step),
                        lambda: update_step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(cond_print_op)
```